# Which is the correct place to save my own application password in cocoa app?

Tags: macos, cocoa

My application name is "Secret Photos". In my application I need store the photos secretly. I have done this part. Now I need to authenticate the user to view the photos. First time while opening the app I will get the password from the user. Now where can I save this password ?
In `Library/Containers` Folder or in `Keychain` ? If I store this password in `Containers` folder anyone can easily view my password.

I have seen similar applications in app store. I can't able to find where those applications are saving their passwords. I have fully checked the containers folder. They are not storing the passwords containers folder. Where those applications are saving their passwords ?

**EDIT 1:**
If I save passwords in Keychain means users can able to see the password(If they know the mac password). Moreover If the user launches the app it prompts for "Secret Photos wants to access your confidential information .... " I don't want this kind of message. I have seen apps that is storing the passwords somewhere else not in containers folder and in keychain.
You can see this app. This is a free app.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/secret-files-x/id740356582?mt=12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keychain is the best place to store passwords. That way a user can sync it to iCloud and between Macs. He also can look it up in the keychain if he has forgotten the password. The documentation by Apple explains a lot more on using it: [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/03tasks/tasks.html)

Comment: If I save passwords in Keychain means users can able to see the password(If they know the mac password). Moreover If the user launches the app it prompts for "Secret Photos wants to access your confidential information .... " I don't want this kind of message.

Comment: Yes, the user can see the password, but if they know the Mac password they could also delete a password file you generate yourself. Same effect. Also, the message appears only once, if the user choose to always allow access.

Comment: Please see the updated question. I want to store the password like the app I have given in the question.

Comment: Best you ask the programmer of the app you linked then.